# How do I configure my ASUS Router RT-N53 to point to one of my computers

Tags: networking, router

I have a small server at home. And between that server and the Internet I have a Asus Router RT-N53.

I found my IP. Using that IP I was connected to my router. My question is: how can I configure my router Asus RT-N53 so that when I try to access my IP it does not connect me to my router but my small server?

I am unsure but I think I have a dynamique IP.

Also, I already own a public server with a static IP. And I know how to setup a proxy server.

My problem is with the router. How do I point my public dynamic IP to my home server and not my router...

Here is a dummy ui of my router: http://event.asus.com/2009/networks/dummy_ui/en/as.html

I just really suck at this networking stuff. I am not even sure where to begin.

Comment: Could you please be a bit more clear? Which IP are you referring to? Local or global?

Comment: Global... I found my IP. -> with google. That IP points to my Router.

Comment: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=port%20forwarding

Answer (score 0):

You need to change 3 things in your router's configuration (ideally).

1) A static local (lan) IP address. Configure your router to always give your server computer the same IP address, for example 192.168.1.105

2) Ports forwarded on your router pointing to that address. For example, for a web server you would choose to forward port 80 to your local IP address.

3) Your ISP probably provides your with a non-static internet IP. A service like no-ip.com will allow you to get around that, you can sign up with them and configure it in your router. Instead of giving people your IP address to connect to you, you would give them an address such as myserver.no-ip.com

You might find the website www.canyouseeme.org helpful in figuring out if the port is forwarded correctly.

Comment: That wouldn't work unless he installs the no-ip client, and being a user of no-ip myself(with a static ip) id have to say that it takes 5 minutes for changes to propagate to servers, which would mean that his site would be down 5 minutes every time his ip changes.

Comment: That's hardly an issue, for most people their IP address doesn't change unless their internet disconnects... in which case 5 minutes of downtime is perfectly acceptable for a home-grade setup.

Comment: I wouldn't be so sure of that. I had a dynamic ip which used to change every hour. 5 minutes is probably still small for a home-grade setup, but it is definitely a noticeable one.

Comment: I have a cloud server with a static IP. I just need to setup a proxy on my cloud server and to point to my home server. That I already know how. My problem is when I access my global IP I get my router. I want it to point to my server. I just don't know how to configure a Asus RT-N53. And I suck at networking.

Comment: I also don't care what port I will be using since I will be pointing with a proxy. My problem is between the router and my home server.